# Sefer Torah holder on Monday and Thursday, standing or sitting during Yehi Ratzon?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minhag, sefer-torah

I am looking for sources that tell us if the person that holds the Sefer Torah should stand up or sit down while the Yehi Ratzon on Mondays and Thursdays are recited?

Comment: The person holding the Sefer Torah never stands. E.g. when there are 2 Seforim, he doesn't stand for Borechu. When there are 3 he doesn't stand for the other Hagbas. (That's besides that the Yehi Ratzon is said while Gelila is being done, so he couldn't possibly stand.) Can not source any of this, but that's how it's been done as long as I can recall in all countries and cities I've been in.